# Footer not showing up?

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I basically copied my header coding and switched some stuff around and it doesn't show up. I don't understand why it wouldn't, unless I'm typing something in wrong.

Here are the two codes:

**Header**

```
<div class="head">
 <div class="centerimg">
 <img src="images/logo.png" width="96" height="82">
 </div>
    .head {background-image:url('images/header_bg.png'); top repeat-x; height: 182px;}
```

**Footer**

```
<div class="footer">
</div>

.footer {background-image:url('images/footer_bg.png'); bottom repeat-x; height: 110px;}
```

Why will the header show up but not the footer?

Comment: Do you have an image named footer_bg.png?

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers do not allow empty `<div>` tags. Your browser may be doing this, which would cause the footer not to show up.

Answer (score 0):

If this is exactly how you have written your code, I'm surprised your header even works.  The way you define .head and .footer isn't done correctly from what I can see.  Also, you are trying to do some shorthand in your CSS, but you are defining the 'position' of the image before the 'attachment', which is out of order.  [Here is a link to more about that](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)  Try adding the following inside of your  and  tags:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .head {background: transparent url('images/header_bg.png') repeat-x 0px 0px; height: 182px;}
  .footer {background:transparent url('images/footer_bg.png') repeat-x 0px 0px; height: 110px;}
</style>
```

Comment: My host provider has it set up so I don't need that kind of stuff. They're kind of like modules I'm typing into which get setup in that way.

Comment: What QVCool said is also a good possibility.  Try adding &nbsp; inside of the .footer <div>.  Some browsers don't allow empty <div>.

Comment: Well, I am unsure if you tried the code the way I suggested, but if you did not, maybe give that a shot?  Also, try manually going to your 'images/footer_bg.png' to make sure it's found?

Comment: Yeah I tried. I doubled checked the paths before I posted this also.

Comment: Is it possible that you didn't close a <div> in the <div class="head"> section?  I see that you have a <div class="head">, but and inside of that is <div class="centerimg">.  However, you only have a single </div> before you do the line of code defining the .head style.  If indeed you don't have a second </div> closing the <div class="head">, perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: You still have an open <div> remaining.  You never close <div id="nav">.  So the code is being read as if everything following the code in the image is part of <div class="head">.  Try making sure all <div> tags are closed and see if that helps the problem.  Also, indentation really helps this.  Personally, every time I go into a new nested element, I tab over.  That helps keep track of which tags remain unclosed.